# Best free (or state / national park) XC Skiing in southern side of Great Lakes area?

Tags: trails, cross-country-skiing, pennsylvania

Planning to do some XC (Cross Country) skiing. I live in SW Virginia.

Criteria:

- Drive < 10 h from SW Virginia
- Dependable snow
- Flat-ish trails (good for xc skiing)
- Ideally: Free or inexpensive ( < $10/ day per person)

Do NOT need the trails to be groomed.

**Top finds so far:**
Both are near Great Lakes so getting good lake effect snow

- Laurel Mountain State Park, PA
  *Grayling, Michigan

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [White Grass Ski Touring Center](https://whitegrass.com/) in the Canaan Valley, West Virginia. I say "possibly" because I haven't been there in 15 years or so, and the snowiness might have changed. Then it had snow when nearby areas did not. As I remember, that was because it was within the lake effect area. We would drive for several hours from the DC suburbs, through totally snowless territory, and then, when we were about to despair, WHAM! Lots of snow on the ground!

I can't remember if it had totally flat areas; the trails I remember were very modestly hilly. An alpine skiier would sneer at their trails. I can't remember how expensive it was, but was very unpretentious, although beautiful.  It had a good restaurant attached, but with a very limited menu.

There is also a downhill resort in the Canaan Valley, not far from Whitegrass.

Answer (score 0):

Oil Creek State Park in Pennsylvania. [Map](https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Oil+Creek+State+Park,+305+State+Park+Rd,+Oil+City,+PA+16301/@39.3312132,-82.9540626,7z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x8832df0613b444af:0x8f48ceee1dcf30a7!2m2!1d-79.6804575!2d41.5151473!3e0).

It's about 7h drive from Blacksburg, va